# How to prompt to user an alert dialog but not when my app is forground?

Tags: android, alert, android-alertdialog

i want to show the user an alert dialog message, that he can choose yes/no
but i want to do that automatical even and mainly when my app is not forground,

like clock alarm, that can jump up to screen in any situation (even if user in call)..

how to do that?
i succeed to do alert.. but its came up just when my app is forground :/
using this guide:
http://www.androidhive.info/2011/09/how-to-show-alert-dialog-in-android/

please help me,
thank's.

Answer (score 2):

You can't, AFAIK, a `Dialog` needs an `Activity`. An option you have that may satisfy your needs is to create an `Activity` with a `Dialog Theme` and call this in a `Receiver`. All you need to do to make it look like an `AlertDialog` is to add

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
```

to the `<activity>` tag in the `manifest`.

[BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)

Comment: there is a sample code how to do it? i didnt understand it well.. i create one more activity with that line in Manifest:  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" but it still not show nothing when i go to the homescreen

Comment: Which part don't you understand? To make the `Activity` look like a `Dialog` you just need to add that code to your `Activity` in the `manifest`. If you want to show it when the app isn't in the foreground then you want to use a `BroadcastReceiver` or have a `Service` running in the background. I don't know exactly what you are looking for but whichever you need there are a lot of examples and tutorials on The Google and SO

Comment: i try it but i cant success to prompt to user something when my app is on the background.. even after i put the line to the Manifest. there is a way to do it?

Comment: Did you try to implement a `BroadcastReceiver` as I suggested? I don't know what action you are expecting to prompt the user

Comment: i want to reminde the user to do something, so when my app is at the background (or if it's imposible.. even when my app killed) i want to write on the screen a message with 2 options.

Comment: like i wrote before.. similarly to clock-alarm

Comment: Then you want to look at [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html). [And check here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459058/alarm-manager-example)