# How to show alertdialog without showing activity

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Is this possible that how to show alertdialog without showing activity?I have researched about  this subject but I did not find any answer

Comment: No. Last I knew, a `Dialog` still needs an `Activity` to exist. See my other comment for a possible soultion

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prompt to user an alert dialog but not when my app is forground?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18240413/how-to-prompt-to-user-an-alert-dialog-but-not-when-my-app-is-forground)

Comment: What is ur use-case ? Maybe there are other components, which u can use!

Comment: If you aren't worried about efficiency you can set your Dialog as it's own activity and set it to the dialog theme in your manifest. android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" But to just popup a Dialog out of the blue isn't possible as far as I know. It needs an Activity context I believe.